# Margin not working with float elements

Tags: html, css

On my web page, I have a logo and a menu that make up header elements and a hero unit under it.
Now I want to give it some bottom margin so there is enough negative space between
header and hero unit but this bottom margin (100px) is not applying.
Same thing if I try to give top margin from hero unit.

```
.header {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 20px auto 100px;
}
```

Here is my working sample [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/AQUCidu/3/edit)

Comment: it does not...both 20px and 100px apply as top margin.

Comment: @Adrift It works perfect and your idea makes sense. I am happy to select your answer if you make one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding a div under it with:

```
.someclass {
     clear: both;
}
```

would help. But even easier is:

```
.header {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 20px auto 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you add the overflow: hidden; the browser will be forced to calculate the size of the elements within, despite them being floated. When the size is calculated, it also knows where to start the margin-bottom.

> One more popular uses of setting overflow, strangely enough, is float clearing. Setting overflow doesn't clear the float at the element, it self-clears. This means that the element with overflow applied (auto or hidden), will extend as large as it needs to encompass child elements inside that are floated (instead of collapsing), assuming that the height isn't declared.

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

The difference between auto and hidden in this case, is that with hidden, it will hide everything that overflows, when it doesn't have enough room anymore, and with auto, it will create a scrollbar.

### EDIT:

Since this question apparently is still active, I'll add the most common way of solving this in the present day:

```
.header:after {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}
```

This is the same as the first method, but then without having to add another element. This is *the* way to go if setting `overflow` is not an option (or even if it is an option, this would be better).

When I first posted this answer, it wasn't an option as it was not supported by IE 6 / 7, which were still broadly used back then.

Comment: Thanks. How would it make difference having `hidden` vs `auto`?

Comment: Since it doesn't have dimensions set, giving it an overflow: hidden calculates everything in the div. So instead of making everything invisible that is outside of the div's dimensions, it makes the dimensions equal to the content of the div.

With overflow on auto, it will automatically set overflow on visible now, since everything is floated.

I hope this is making sense. If not i'll try to explain clearer.

Comment: With my case, both `overflow:auto` and `overflow:hidden` give a working outcome so I am still not 100% clear about this concept. My basic understanding about overflow was controlling overflow element with scroll.

Comment: I added more explanation for this particular case. Setting hidden, hides everything that flows out of the content box, setting auto, creates a scrollbar if needed and otherwise just creates as much room it needs, setting scroll creates a scrollbar, needed or not, and setting visible makes content flow out of the bounding box, without hiding it, but without it taking more space than it's bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a clearfix to your header or wrapper tag.  This is useful bit of css to include in your file.  More about the clearfix can be found here

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a problem in your margin attribute order.

If I change your property from: 20px auto 100px;  to: **20px 0px 100px 0px** then I have bottom space appearing.

Comment: Thanks for your input. There are different patterns of writing shorthand css values and 20px auto 100px means to apply `top 20px` , `right, left: auto`, `bottom 100px`.

Comment: I was aware of different patterns but not this one, just seeing this now. Any progress so far on this initial problem ?

Comment: Adding either `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` worked for me.