# How to add margin next to a float element

Tags: css, css-float

I have text between 2 block float elements and I want to add an additional indentation to the right for a `quote` id element inside the `p` paragraph. The problem is that `margin-left` doesn't work next to a float element and if I use the `position: relative` method, like in the shown example, then the text will clip the right float block. Is there a way to move the `quote` text to the right without the clipping?

```css
#left-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px
}

#right-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#quote{
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left-block"></div>
  <div id="right-block"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis?
  <p id="quote">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis? Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum."</p>
    Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

For an exact example you can look at [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules) at the line `Tacitus records a special affinity of the Germanic peoples for Hercules. In chapter 3 of his Germania, Tacitus states:` You can see that the indented text that follows is essentially between 2 floating images.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a `<blockquote>` element in html, which is used for quotes? Regarding your question: You can't nest `<p>` inside p-elements. How should it look like? Do you have a reference image?

Comment: instead of `left` set `margin: 0 auto` with `max-width: 80%` you can change the unit according to your need!! By doing this you will have spacing on both side of your quote. Apart that you can use `padding: 0 4rem` again change the unit according to your need.

Comment: @cloned i've tried to mess with `<blockquote>` element but it didn't really do much of a difference in this case. If you want an example you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules at the line `Tacitus records a special affinity of the Germanic peoples for Hercules. In chapter 3 of his Germania, Tacitus states:` You can see that the indented text that follows is essentially between 2 floating images.

Comment: What should happen to the indent when the text inside the quote drops below the floated images? Do you want the text line to be 30px indented from the left edge of the body, or maintain the same indent as the lines above it.

Comment: @Alohci I would like it indented 30px from the left edge of the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that isn't perfect but works, is to simply add `overflow: hidden` in to the `quote` element. The explanation seems to be written here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718157/18429900

The only issue with this is that it doesn't move the text to the left once it goes lower than the block height as show in the example below.

```css
#left-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px
}

#right-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#quote{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left-block"></div>
  <div id="right-block"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis?
  <p id="quote">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis? Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum."</p>
    Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin is correctly applied.
The problem is that your block is before in your html and it you should be after.
So, for what you are trying to achieve it is better to use `display:flex`

So I restructure your html, by placing a "container" and applying the flex.
Then, I put all your `p` into a `div` and place the right block below.

As you added a `left` to your `#quote` you need to adjust `width` of it too.

So I could remove your float.

### DEMO

```css
#left-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  /*float: left;*/
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px
}

#right-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  /*float: right;*/
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#quote{
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div id="left-block"></div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis?</p>
      <p id="quote">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis? Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum."</p>
      <p>
        Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-block"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that i wish to keep the open float method. I added an edit to the question where you can see the how it's supposed to look like. You can see that the blocks/pictures aren't actually leveled equally.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*  use a margin, but the value has to be larger than the width of the floated elements, since the margin is measured from to side of the parent element, not taking the floated element into account:

(no need for relative position BTW)

```css
#left-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px
}

#right-block{
  height: 150px;
  width:50px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#quote{
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left-block"></div>
  <div id="right-block"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis?
  <p id="quote">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem natus sit, reiciendis dolore accusantium mollitia in quia ipsa itaque iure, eaque nobis? Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum."</p>
    Voluptate corrupti excepturi quaerat commodi, aut illo dolorum.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the easy way to fix it but then i can't really use this `quote` anywhere else since the margin value will depend on the float block width.

Comment: well, I doubt that you'll find another way just with CSS. There might be a solution with JS, but that would have to be rather complex, I suppose.